# validate_presence_of shoulda spec and default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, shoulda

I have some code in a Rails model that does this:

```
has_one :plan
validates_presence_of :plan
```

And used to do this:

```
after_initialize :set_plan

def set_plan
  self.plan ||= FreePlan.new
end
```

and now does:

```
def plan
  super || (self.plan = FreePlan.new)
end
```

Now, however, this test fails:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:plan) }
```

The new code is nicer in that it doesn't always have to look up a plan object in the DB for every instantiation of this object, but I'm curious what the test is doing in terms of the object under test and its lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is happening:

with the older code, `after_initialize` is called, and the value is automatically populated.  But it's possible to subsequently set `plan` to nil and then try and save it.

With the new code, `valid?` is going to call the `plan` method and therefore  populate it, so that when the test suite inspects `errors`, it's not going to find any for plan.

Perhaps the best course of action is to remove the line from the test suite and add one ensuring that plan is never nil.

Comment: This is correct. There's no need to add a validation that the plan is never nil; such a validation would never fail.